# Склонение иностранных слов в оригинальном написании

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, заимствования, латиница-кириллица, апостроф

В технических текстах иногда приходиться использовать иностранные (английские) слова, записанные, собственно, по-английски.

Уместность такого подхода является отдельным вопросом, но, на мой взгляд, иногда это уместно.

Три варианта заголовка одного и того же документа:

> - Установка и использование TypeScript/JavaScript-овых language server-ов
> - Установка и использование TypeScript/JavaScript'овых language server'ов
> - Установка и использование языковых серверов для TypeScript и JavaScript

Выбирая между вариантами написания через дефис и через апостроф, какой является более правильным, более рекомендованным? Или, может быть, им является какой-то другой?

Третий вариант неплох, но он находится за рамками вопроса. Бывают ситуации, когда такая "гладкость" выходит боком.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае принято использовать апостроф. Из "Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации"<sup>1</sup>:

> §115. (...) Апострофом отделяются русские окончания и суффиксы от предшествующей части слова, передаваемой латинскими буквами.

Но стоит этим пользоваться в меру. Я понимаю, что вы привели эту фразу просто в качестве примера, но я всё же прокомментирую её.

Во-первых, *TypeScript* и *JavaScript* не являются прилагательными. Вы же пишете *language server'ов*, а не *language'вых server'ов*.

Во-вторых, вся фраза *TypeScript/JavaScript language server* использует внутри себя английский синтаксис, поэтому нет большого смысла демонстрировать эти внутренние связи ещё и с помощью русских окончаний, достаточно показать как главное слово *server* зависит от русской части вашей фразы:

*Установка и использование TypeScript/JavaScript language server'ов*

В-третьих, в вашем примере термин *TypeScript/JavaScript language server* занимает большую часть фразы: уж проще тогда всю фразу переработать и избавиться от необходимости использования русских окончаний:

*TypeScript/JavaScript language server: установка и использование*

---

1. Валгина Н. С., Еськова Н. А., Иванова О. Е., Кузьмина С. М., Лопатин В. В., Чельцова Л. К. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под редакцией В. В. Лопатина. — 2-е изд., испр. и доп. — М.: Эксмо, 2007.